# Laravel 5 Routing - understanding

Tags: php, laravel, filter, routes, laravel-5

I am trying to debug a Laravel 5.o code. I have learnt from [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing).

But what I am facing, is not like that. What I am trying to debug is something like this -

```
    <?php

    get("/test",function(){
        return $webinar = \App\Webinar::with('subscribers')->find(1);
    });

    Route::controllers([
        'auth' => 'Auth\GTWAuthController',
        'members' => 'MembersController',
        'customers' => 'CustomersController'
    ]);

    resource('users', 'Resources\UsersController');
    resource('users.subscribers-lists', 'Resources\SubscribersListController');
    resource('users.subscribers-lists.subscribers', 'Resources\SubscribersController');
    resource('users.webinars', 'Resources\WebinarsController');
    resource('users.panelists', 'Resources\PanelistsController');

    resource('qas', 'Resources\QAController');

    Route::group(array('prefix' => '/'), function() {
        Route::get('/webinar/{webinar_id}/{subscriber}', 
            array('as' => 'site.webinar', 'uses' => 'WebinarController@index'));


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////Testing
    Route::get('test','CustomersController@getTest');
    Route::post('add_question','CustomersController@add_question');
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        Route::get('/webinar/{webinar_id}/panelist', array('middleware' => 'user.panelist', 'as' => 'site.panelist.webinar', 'uses' => 'WebinarController@index'));
    });
```

So, I can't understand how routs are working, can anyone help meplahow this outs are working?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I don't know if your question will be downvoted for not being specific, but I will assume you want to know more about advanced routing, like resources and prefixes.

A resource creates automatically the route names for all the possible methods to interact with a resource or model.

For example:

```
resource('client', 'ClientController');
```

With that single line of code inside your routes.php file, laravel 5.0 you now have the equivalent to:

```
//Uses show method, where you can return a view with a single client information
Route::get('client/{client}', [
    'as'=>'client.show'
    'uses'=>'ClientController@show'
]);

//Uses the index method, where you can return a view with a list of all the clients
Route::get('client', [
    'as'=>'client.index'
    'uses'=>'ClientController@index'
]);

//Uses the edit method, where you can return a view with an edit form for that specific client
Route::get('client/{client}/edit', [
    'as'=>'client.index'
    'uses'=>'ClientController@edit'
]);
```

**AND SO ON** It creates the destroy, update, create and all the possible methods, and also the proper route methods like PATCH, PUT, DELETE, POST, GET so you don't have to code it all.

A group is simply a group of routes that share a common feature. In the example you provided, the routes have a common prefix '/' I don't understand why, but it is most commonly seen with a prefix like:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'academy'), function() {
        Route::get('/webinar/{webinar_id}/{subscriber}', 
            array('as' => 'site.webinar', 'uses' => 'WebinarController@index'));
```

So, everytime you enter an url like `www.myapp.com/academy/whatever` it will use the routes inside that group.

Any other question? remember to visit Laracasts.com and you will learn a bunch of it in 5 minutes